# Convert input value into a string

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I am having trouble converting an input value into a string. 
HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email Ex: john321" id="grailedemail">
<input type="text" placeholder="Domain Ex: @gmail.com" id="graileddomain">
```

JS:

```
let email = document.getElementById("grailedemail").value;
let domain = document.getElementById("graileddomain").value;
let _ge = grailed_email.toString();
let _gd = grailed_domain.toString();


let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 1;
let emailAltered = `${_ge}+${randNum}${_gd}`;
```

I dont know if this is the right use of **.toString** method.

The output of the above returns this:

> {
>           "email":"+388321",
>           "pass":"password",
>               }

Expected Output:

> {
>           "email":"johndoe+388321@gmail.com",
>           "pass":"password",
>               }
>   (I want to get whatever the user inputs)
>   Where before the plus there is supposed to be the variable **_ge** or **email**
>   And after the number, there is supposed to be the variable  **_gd** or **domain**

Comment: what is this grailed_email and grailde_domain ?

Comment: Why do you convert `toString` value that is already a string?

Comment: At what event do you get those values? On submit, document.load, input.change?
We need more context.

Comment: I'm confused by the question, `HTMLInputElement.value` is [already a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value).

Comment: There is no way the code you have provided could produce the object you describe — you don't create an object at all!. It looks like a significant chunk of your code is missing. You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a typo.

The variable that contains the email is the `email`, and the variable that contains the domain is the `domain`, but you're using `grailed_email` and `grailed_domain`, and that's why the wanted data isn't in the string. Change your code to:

```
let grailed_email = document.getElementById("grailedemail").value; // Variable grailed_email fixed
let grailed_domain = document.getElementById("graileddomain").value; //  Variable grailed_domain fixed
let _ge = grailed_email.toString();
let _gd = grailed_domain.toString();


let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 1;
let emailAltered = `${_ge}+${randNum}${_gd}`;
```

Comment: So check if the `grailed_email` and `grailed_domain` have the right value. Also try to not convert it to string

Comment: I just want to get whatever the user inputs

Comment: @MiguelBetancourt in that case you should add more information to your question.

Comment: As @Smollet777 said, the input is a string. Why you want to convert it to string again?

Comment: typo related issues doesn't require a full answer to address them, a comment is sufficient

Answer (score -1):

try this way

```js
function debug() {
  var email = document.getElementById("grailedemail").value;
  var domain = document.getElementById("graileddomain").value;
  var _ge = email.toString();  
  var _gd = domain.toString(); 

  let randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999) + 1;
  let emailAltered = `${_ge}+${randNum}${_gd}`;

  document.getElementById('debug').textContent = emailAltered;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Johndoe" placeholder="Email Ex: john321" id="grailedemail">
<input type="text" value="@gmailcom" placeholder="Domain Ex: @gmail.com" id="graileddomain">
<input type="button" onclick="debug()" value="Submit">
<p id="debug"></p>
```

Comment: It did not work. Do I have to convert them to strings?

Comment: @MiguelBetancourt I have update my answer. And it works as per your expected output. I have also give the jsfiddle URL. please check it.

Comment: As a suggestion, code snippets make it easier to play with the code while staying on SO.

Comment: @stealththeninja Thanks for suggestion. For this reason , I have down vote when I gave working code ?

Comment: @SachinShah didn’t downvote. My guess would be that your answer only provided code with no explanation. For OP and others, it’s helpful to explain why the code posted in the question didn’t work and how your solution fixes the problem.

Comment: @stealththeninja ok , if you fell my answer it right then upvote it. :) or you may post the correct answer.